# How do i make something like mobizen logo pop ups on screen in kivi python

Tags: python, android

*MOST OF US PROBABLY KNOW BUT MOBIZEN IS AN MOBILE SCREEN RECORDING APP*

***The part that i want to know is how,***

***mobizen logo stays on screen and,***

***toolbar appears whenever you click
the logo stays on screen even while phone is on another app,***

***where i should research to make something like this.***

> (I'm using 'kivy' library in PYTHON)

-PurpleLime

REGARDS

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i've found, its named "Floating Application" guys check documentation of it